How to solve direct lattice error in Quantum ESPRESSO while running pw2wannier90.x?
This is my scf input file
&CONTROL
  calculation = 'scf'
  outdir = './out/'
  prefix = 'MoS2'
  pseudo_dir = '/home/sana/pseudo'
/
&SYSTEM
  ecutrho =  120
  ecutwfc =  30
  ibrav = 4
  a=3.184066,
  b=3.184066,
  c=18.127112,
  nat = 3
  nbnd = 30
  input_dft = 'hse'
  exx_fraction = 0.25
  nqx1 = 2
  nqx2 = 2
  nqx3 = 1
  ntyp = 2
/
&ELECTRONS
  conv_thr = 1.0d-6
  mixing_beta =   0.7
/
ATOMIC_SPECIES
Mo     95.96 Mo.pbe-spn-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF
S      32.065 S.pbe-n-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF
ATOMIC_POSITIONS crystal
Mo           0.0000000000       0.0000000000       0.5000000000 
S            0.3333333333       0.6666666667       0.4217548051
S            0.3333333333       0.6666666667       0.5782450789
K_POINTS automatic
6 6 2 0 0 0

And this is my mos2.win input file
#CONTROL
num_bands = 30
num_wann = 11

num_iter = 20

dis_win_min = -8
dis_win_max = 5
dis_froz_min = -8
dis_froz_max = 3.5

#PLOTING
bands_plot = .true.

begin kpoint_path
G 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000   K 0.3333 0.3333 0.0000
K 0.3333 0.3333 0.0000   M 0.5000 0.0000 0.0000
M 0.5000 0.0000 0.0000   G 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
end kpoint_path

#SYSTEM
begin unit_cell_cart
ang
3.184066 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 3.184066 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 18.127112
end unit_cell_cart

begin atoms_frac
Mo 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.5000000000 
S  0.3333333333 0.6666666667 0.4217548051
S  0.3333333333 0.6666666667 0.5782450789
end atoms_frac

# PROJECTIONS
guiding_centres = .true.

begin projections
Mo: dxy; dyz; dxz; dx2-y2; dz2
S: px; py; pz
end projections
 
# KPOINTS
mp_grid = 6 6 2

begin kpoints
0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.00000000 0.16666667 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.00000000 0.33333333 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.00000000 0.50000000 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.00000000 0.66666667 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.00000000 0.83333333 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.16666667 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.16666667 0.16666667 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.16666667 0.33333333 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.16666667 0.50000000 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.16666667 0.66666667 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.16666667 0.83333333 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.33333333 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.33333333 0.16666667 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.33333333 0.33333333 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.33333333 0.50000000 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.33333333 0.66666667 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.33333333 0.83333333 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.50000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.50000000 0.16666667 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.50000000 0.33333333 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.50000000 0.50000000 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.50000000 0.66666667 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.50000000 0.83333333 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.66666667 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.66666667 0.16666667 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.66666667 0.33333333 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.66666667 0.50000000 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.66666667 0.66666667 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.66666667 0.83333333 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.83333333 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.83333333 0.16666667 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.83333333 0.33333333 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.83333333 0.50000000 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.83333333 0.66666667 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.83333333 0.83333333 0.00000000 0.0277778
0.00000000 0.00000000 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.00000000 0.16666667 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.00000000 0.33333333 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.00000000 0.50000000 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.00000000 0.66666667 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.00000000 0.83333333 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.16666667 0.00000000 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.16666667 0.16666667 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.16666667 0.33333333 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.16666667 0.50000000 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.16666667 0.66666667 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.16666667 0.83333333 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.33333333 0.00000000 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.33333333 0.16666667 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.33333333 0.33333333 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.33333333 0.50000000 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.33333333 0.66666667 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.33333333 0.83333333 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.50000000 0.00000000 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.50000000 0.16666667 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.50000000 0.33333333 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.50000000 0.50000000 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.50000000 0.66666667 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.50000000 0.83333333 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.66666667 0.00000000 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.66666667 0.16666667 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.66666667 0.33333333 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.66666667 0.50000000 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.66666667 0.66666667 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.66666667 0.83333333 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.83333333 0.00000000 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.83333333 0.16666667 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.83333333 0.33333333 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.83333333 0.50000000 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.83333333 0.66666667 0.50000000 0.0277778
0.83333333 0.83333333 0.50000000 0.0277778
end kpoints

I face direct lattice error in pw2wannier90.x.
The error is direct lattice. How can I solve this error?

Hi! Also note that the input calculation preceding the Wannier calculations should be on a uniform mesh from 0 to 1 like in your .win file. Actually, this should be exactly the same mesh. Also, I think you should not include the weights in the .win file.

A direct lattice mismatch means that the unit cell specified in your PWscf input file is not the same as the one you specified in the wannier90 input file. (The tolerance is pretty tight: you have to write in quite a lot of decimal places if the expansion doesn't terminate.) Let's have a look at yours.
In your scf input, you specified ibrav = 4: this indicates a hexagonal or trigonal unit cell, with lattice vectors $a_1 = (a, 0, 0)$, $a_2 = (-a/2, a\sqrt{3}/2, 0)$, $a_3 = (0, 0, c)$, where $a, b, c$ are the parameters you input just below ibrav (in angstroms). (If you wanted them in bohr instead, you'd use a -> celldm(1), c/a -> celldm(3).)
Anyway, your wannier90 input file has a tetragonal unit cell, not a trigonal one: the second cell vector differs. To fix it, change ibrav to 6 in the scf input, specifying a tetragonal unit cell.
